# Using DDE to get the source of a webpage

Tags: c#, vb.net, dde, ndde

Ok. I know I can use DDE to get the URL of a web page, and even open a specific page in an outside webbrowser such as Firefox. I was wondering what would be needed to get the source of the displayed webpage. If there is anyone who could help I would greatly appreciate it. I am using vb.net, but I can easily take any C# examples available. I have googled and can't seem to find much.

Answer (score 1):

Rough and ready, but :

```
using System;

namespace So2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

            System.Net.WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();

            string source = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            Console.WriteLine(source);

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response.I know you can use a web request to get the source of a webpage, but I know that specific instances of a webpage can have slightly different information. So I wanted to read the source of an already opened webpage in firefox.